# Problem with pyinstaller and multiple tkinter windows

Tags: python-2.7

se additional windows are not loaded and not working properly. Looks like they are ignored in the conversion process.

I have to say that my program runs smoothly in pycharm so there is no error in the code.

I couldn't find anything relevant in my google search.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: What are the contents of your new window? There might be an error occurring that is stopping the code from execution. Use `pyinstaller --console filename,py` and copy paste the error seen in the terminal

Comment: Unfortunately there is no error in the conversion that ends with the message:
"8634 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully."
My code in those new windows has a bunch of RadioButtons, Labels etc.
Looks like the new Toplevel windows are ignored for a reason I can't imagine right now.

Comment: Now i mean, when you run the exe after new code, it will show a terminal with it. It might show an error when you open a window.

Comment: I got you! The .ico created the problem, I could see that in the console, thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be many reasons as to why this happens, the one likely is the code execution got halted because there is an error in the code. But since you don't have any interface to view the error, it is not seen. So change your `pyinstaller` code to:

```
pyinstaller file.py
```

Now the exe will open with a terminal. Inside that terminal you will see the error code. Since in your case, it says error about ico, you need to place all the required dependencies of your code in the same directory as the exe is. So once you copy the ico file on to the project directory, or if it was some other issue, after solving it you can use your original `pyinstaller` code and get rid of the console.